# Displaying all images which are present in a folder in ionic 3 with angular

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have list of image files on device in Android/data/myApp folde. I want to display all images in my app. I've tried every possible path in src attribute but nothing works. I've also tried change src to ng-src or data-ng-src. Nothing works and if any one having this kind of code let me know. ionic with angular 4

Answer (score 0):

try this and provide more details where are those images located exactly?

```
  <img src="assets/imgs/yourimage.png">
```